# Spring Boot application failing on AutoConfigurationImportFilter not being able to be built but no class specified

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

So I go to start my app and it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter
at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:167)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:104)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationImportFilters(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:266)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.filter(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:237)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:102)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.process(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:386)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:828)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:563)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:271)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:91)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:692)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:530)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
at com.bayer.aws.agent.GeneEditBarcodeAgentApplication.main(GeneEditBarcodeAgentApplication.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition] is not assignable to [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter]
at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:162)
... 20 common frames omitted
```

It's not specifying what class it's failing to build however and I've got beans for all the classes that spring would try to build so I'm just confused on how to figure out what class it's missing. I really don't want to build beans for all of the classes in my apps. (like my models and controllers) Does anyone know how to go about finding out what class spring is unable to build? I can post up some of my code here but I have to be careful as this is for work so I will post up code by request for anyone that needs to see something. Thanks so much in advance for any help you can give me!

Thanks,
Jon

Edit: Here's the code for the application

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GeneEditBarcodeAgentApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Starting app");
        SpringApplication.run(GeneEditBarcodeAgentApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the `GeneEditBarcodeAgentApplication` into the question please?

Comment: @andrewdleach Put the code in there. Thanks!

Comment: What about your POM file? Are there no other `.java` files?

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue. It got resolved by deleting spring-boot-autoconfigure folder under C:\Users\currentUser\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot

Then in eclipse do maven update.